# Best way to find_or_create but do it with an ID with potential of multiples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

So my question is, this following code snippet works fine when there is only ONE emergency contact. It would look for a ContactDetail with the type_of 'emergency', then create it if there isn't one and update it if there is. How would I do this if there were more than one ContactDetail with the type_of "emergency"? Ideally i'd like to update it VIA the ID of the ContactDetail Model

```
  class Api::Practice::ClientsController < PracticeBaseController

    def update
      @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
        @user.update(user_params)

        emergency = @user.contact_details.find_or_create_by(type_of: 'emergency')
        emergency.update(emergency_contact_params)

        render json: @user, serializer: UserSerializer
    end

    private

    def emergency_contact_params
      params.fetch(:emergency_contact, {}).permit(:name,:phone,:email)
    end
  end
```

thanks again guys!

Comment: If the user can have more than 1 emergency contact_details, you need to supply another field to identify the specific contact_detail you want to find. Maybe use the email.

Comment: Hey thanks Pablo, is there no way to go through the ID?

Comment: Yes, but do you have the id to search? How are your Client and ContactDetail models? How does the user select new emergency contacts?

Comment: `User.contact_details.where(type_of: "emergency")` would return all emergency

Comment: @eti Let talk about business rule. If you have multiple contact details, how do you select which one you want to update? Or you will update all? Is there any fields in `emergency_contact_params` can use to select appropriate contact detail?

Comment: @Tai hey, so Ideally i'd update them by the ID. There will be multiple of them in one page so we should be able to update them all at the same time.

`create_table :contact_details do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, null: false
      t.string :name, default: ''
      t.string :email, default: ''
      t.string :profession, default: ''
      t.string :phone, default: ''
      t.string :relationship, default: ''
      t.integer :type_of
      t.boolean :consent_yn, default: false
      t.boolean :deleted_yn, default: false
      t.timestamps` 

is the model

Comment: @eti. I'd like to know how the new contacts (or the original contacts that would be updated) are filled in the view and passed to the Controller. When the user edits or adds contacts: does the view shows the existing contacts (name, email, phone) and allows to change theses fields? Or he needs enters this information?

Comment: I think your approach would work fine if you plan to have a single ContactDetail record for each User. Otherwise you should pass the id of the ContactDetail from the client with the update request and use that to look it up.